# php array_diff with sql query and $REQUEST

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I want to use `array_diff` with the result of an mysql query and the result of an `$REQUEST` here is what I tried:

```
while($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) 
{
$Bestand = $resultarray3['Bestand']
}
$Ergebnis = array_diff($_REQUEST['Menge'], $Bestand);
```

I got this error by using it: `Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array in /var/www/html/lager_management/warenkorb.php on line 143`

Example for the array $Bestand:

```
Array ( [0] => 20 [1] => 250 [2] => 90 )
```

Example for the array $Menge:

```
Array ([0] => 10 [1] => 45 [3] => 80 )
```

Comment: 1) Why are you not doing this in the SQL query to begin with, 2) yeah, because `$Bestand` is not an array, it's just the last value from the database.

Comment: Hi, see the PHP manual for the correct syntax of array_diff(). the seconed argument ($Bestand in ur case) must also be an array. so change it to $Bestand = array(resultarray3['Bestand']);

Comment: @AyyappanSekar i knew this and used also array thats not working

Comment: @Pgr456: Hi, it seems u r getting a value from $_REQUEST array. it must also be an array.. check that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are replacing the varible each time in loop.
Try this

`$Bestand =array();
while($resultarray3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3)) 
{
$Bestand[] = $resultarray3['Bestand']
}
$Ergebnis = array_diff($_REQUEST['Menge'], $Bestand);`

Need to change/Modify

```
$Bestand=array()
```

and

```
$Bestand[] = $resultarray3['Bestand']
```

Comment: When i `print_r` the array `Ergebniss` i get the values from `$_REQUEST['Menge']` and not the values from the `array_diff`

Comment: array_diff gives the difference between two arrays.
Can you please edit your post and add possible array OR you can refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php for help

Comment: I saw your code ,array_diff returns an array containing all the entries from array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.
Your both the array's are different it will return $_REQUEST['Menge'] as a result

Comment: Actually this is expected behavior of array_diff
If you want to test it you can swipe parameters 
`$Ergebnis = array_diff($Bestand,$_REQUEST['Menge']);` at this time you will get $Bestand if you `print_r($Ergebnis);`

Answer (score 0):

use the array, not simple var

```
$Bestand[] = $resultarray3['Bestand'];
```

Comment: i tried this too gives me same result

Comment: what result is 

    var_dump($Bestand);

before

    $Ergebnis = array_diff($_REQUEST['Menge'], $Bestand);

Comment: the var_dump is : `array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "20" [1]=> string(3) "250" [2]=> string(2) "90" }`

Comment: $Ergebnis = array_diff($_REQUEST['Menge'], array()); return same result (Warning: array_diff(): Argument #2 is not an array in )?